# Runtime Error when using a for loop inside a while loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

This is a hangman project I'm working on. Inside the guessing function, a for loop is used to add onclick functions to the buttons and another for loop is used to check whether the button's text(a letter) is inside the word. Also a while loop is wrapping these for loops up to check whether the user is out of guesses or he guesses the word. But when I try to run it, browser crashes and I have no clue why it happens.

Also I wonder if I can put the while loop conditions inside the for loop as they works quite similar :/

Here is my code:

```js
    window.onload = function() {
        var letters = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z";
        var category = ["Premier Leaque Football Teams", "Films", "Cities"];
        var wordlist = [
            ["everton", "liverpool", "swansea", "chelsea", "hull", "manchester-city", "newcastle-united"],
            ["alien", "dirty-harry", "gladiator", "finding-nemo", "jaws"],
            ["manchester", "milan", "madrid", "amsterdam", "prague"]
        ];
        var hints = [
            ["Based in Mersyside", "Based in Mersyside", "First Welsh team to reach the Premier Leauge", "Owned by A russian Billionaire", "Once managed by Phil Brown", "2013 FA Cup runners up", "Gazza's first club"],
            ["Science-Fiction horror film", "1971 American action film", "Historical drama", "Anamated Fish", "Giant great white shark"],
            ["Northern city in the UK", "Home of AC and Inter", "Spanish capital", "Netherlands capital", "Czech Republic capital"]
        ]
        var buttons = document.getElementById("buttons");
        var showCategory = document.getElementById("show_category");
        var hyphens = document.getElementById("hyphens");
        var showLives = document.getElementById("show_lives");
        var showClue = document.getElementById("show_clue");
        var showHint = document.getElementById("show_hint");
        var playAgain = document.getElementById("play_again");
    
        letters = letters.split(" ");
        
        var letters_ul = document.createElement("ul");
        for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            var letters_li = document.createElement("li");
            var letters_button = document.createElement("button");
            letters_button.innerHTML = letters[i];
            letters_li.appendChild(letters_button);
            letters_ul.appendChild(letters_li);
        }
        buttons.appendChild(letters_ul);
    
        initialize = function() {
            var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * category.length);
            var w = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordlist[c].length);
            var word = wordlist[c][w];
            var lives = 10;
            showCategory.innerHTML = "The Chosen Category is " + category[c];
            hyphens.innerHTML = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
                hyphens.innerHTML += "-";
            }
            showLives.innerHTML = "You have " + lives + " lives"
            showClue.innerHTML = "Clue : -";
            showHint.addEventListener("click", function(){
                showClue.innerHTML = "Clue : " + hints[c][w];
            })
            playAgain.addEventListener("click", function(){
                initialize();
            })
            guessing(word, lives);
        }
        
        guessing = function(word, lives) {
            var button_list = document.querySelectorAll("#buttons ul li button");
            var isWord = false;
            while (lives > 0 && !isWord) {
                for (var i = 0; i < button_list.length; i++) {
                    button_list[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
                        var h = "";
                            for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
                                if (word[j] === e.target.innerHTML) {
                                    h += e.target.innerHTML;
                                } else if (hyphens.innerHTML[j] === word[j]) {
                                    h += "";
                                } else {
                                    h += "-";
                                }
                                if (hyphens.innerHTML === h && lives > 0) {
                                    lives--;
                                    showLives.innerHTML = "You have " + lives + " lives";
                                } else if (lives === 0 && !isWord) {
                                    showLives.innerHTML = "Game Over!";
                                } else if (hyphens.innerHTML === word) {
                                    showLives.innerHTML = "You Win!";
                                    isWord = true;
                                }
                                hyphens.innerHTML = h;
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
            
        initialize();
    }
```

```css
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
        background-color: goldenrod;
        font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    #buttons ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #buttons ul li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #buttons ul li button {
        padding: 10px 15px;
        border: 1px solid white;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: white;
        color: goldenrod;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    #buttons ul li button:hover {
        background-color: goldenrod;
        color: white;
    }
    #buttons ul li button:active, #buttons ul li button:visited {
        opacity: 0.5 !important;
        background-color: goldenrod !important;
        color: white !important;
    }
    #hyphens {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
    #hangman {
        border: 2px dashed white;
    }
    .container #show_hint, .container #play_again{
        color: white;
        background-color: goldenrod;
        padding: 20px 40px;
        margin: 15px;
        border: 1px solid white;
    }
    .container #show_hint:hover, .container #play_again:hover {
        background-color: white;
        color: goldenrod;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="description" content="hangman">
            <meta name="keywords" content="hangman">
            <meta name="author" content="Nick Hui">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Hangman</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="hangman.css">
            <script src="hangman.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>HANGMAN</h1>
            <h2>VANILLA JAVASCRIPT HANGMAN GAME</h2>
            <p>Use the alphabet below to guess the word, or click hint to get a clue.</p>
            <div id="buttons"></div>
            <p id="show_category"></p>
            <div id="hyphens"></div>
            <p id="show_lives">You have 10 lives</p>
            <p id="show_clue">Clue: -</p>
            <canvas id="hangman"></canvas>
            <div class="container">
                <button id="show_hint">HINT</button>
                <button id="play_again">Play again</button>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The `while` evaluates instantly but your onclick function doesnt. This is a never ending loop and makes your browser crash

Comment: So should i put the while loop inside the addEventListeners or how can i fix it?

Comment: You should not put the while. Make a function "checkLetter" that checks if the letter is correct and the rest of your logic, then add the event listener to click and call that function: `button_list[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){ checkLetter(this.innerText) })` something like this (for every letter `i`).